# your app loads indefinitely upon launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, splash-screen

I have an app which works fine on below devices.

iPhone 4s (iOS 7.1)
iPhone 5 (iOS 9.1)
iPhone 6 (iOS 9.1)

However app is rejecting saying below rejection.

> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad and iPhone running iOS 9.1 on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks.
>
> - App did not load its contents, did not load beyond the flash screen.

However when I run this from my side, its working fine but it has problem at Apple end only. I don't know how can app run at my end and its giving problem at Apple end only? I tried to upload with iOS 8.4, but still Apple reply still we can't go beyond splash screen.

***Did anyone face such issue OR does anyone point me where I can be wrong?***

***I have uploaded 6 builds and all are rejected saying same reason.***

### *Note: Same app was working fine earlier (before iOS 9.1 release), but when I try to upload now, it is giving this error.*

***The biggest challenge for me is, I don't know what is the problem, but I need to FIX this problem***

---

### Edit 1

I have first screen as language screen where I have animation of images.

```
animationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1080, 1920)];
animationImageView.hidden = NO;
animationImageView.animationImages = mArray;
animationImageView.animationDuration = 1.5;
animationImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
[animationImageView startAnimating];
```

Comment: Parker, Did you check your app through test flight  in iPad with iOS 9.1

Comment: I checked it through diawi.com and its working fine...

Comment: Are there any warnings when you build? Have you tried `Product ... Analyze`?

Comment: @GlennRay : check my answer... I found an issue....

Comment: @satheesh : check my answer... I found an issue....

Comment: I encountered a similar problem. I was able to run my app in the simulator as well as on the actual device but it was still rejected by the App Store due to the same reasons as above. I even tried running my app using Test Flight, but wasn't able to replicate the so-called 'bug'. My app was able to run successfully using Test Flight.

Comment: @mechdon : did you fix the issue? if you want to replicate this bug, upload the app and open the app using testflight... make sure you click Open button on testflight to see issue and not directly open the app from the installed apps...

Comment: Hi Fahim, I did run the app using testflight, and it was running fine without any issues. I'm puzzled why the App Store rejected my app saying that it did not load beyond the flash screen. In any case, I've resubmitted my app and am awaiting review.

Comment: @mechdon : In testflight, did you click Open button or just open app like normal by clicking on app icon? I am asking because you will get this error only if you open through testflight...

Comment: I open the app through testflight, but I was able to run the app without any issue.

Comment: @mechdon : not sure then why... ask Apple to send the log file... it will help you.. Apple also sent me log file after a fight with them... i found the issue in log file they sent...

Comment: Thanks Fahim, I'll do that. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After testing on testflight, I found a problem.

If I open the app after clicking app icon, it was working fine.

***The problem comes when I click Open button from testflight***

When I click Open button, `launchOptions` in AppDelegate was not nil, so the code in push was going wrong and internally it was crashing but still app was hanged at splash screen (*not sure why though*)

*Below is what I have when I print `launchOptions` in AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`*

```
launchOptions==={
    UIApplicationLaunchOptionsSourceApplicationKey = "com.apple.TestFlight";
}
```

*So I changed my code to below and all is working perfectly.*

```
NSLog(@"launchOptions===%@", launchOptions);

if (launchOptions!=nil) {
    NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    NSLog(@"userInfo===%@", userInfo);
    NSLog(@"userInfo===%d", userInfo.count);

    if (userInfo.count>=1) {
          // here is my code on what to do if i click on push
    }
}
```

*Do let me know if someone is not clear*

***It was crashing saying below***

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSPlaceholderString initWithString:]: nil argument'

So I feel problem was at line below.

```
NSString *badge =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [apsInfo objectForKey:@"badge"]];
```

But after putting above condition, all was working fine.

Comment: Parker , Better try Test Flight to test your final application it's always fine :)

Comment: Two things: 1. the crash is related an `initWithString:` call with a nil argument, which does not seem to match any of the code you quote above. 2. As far as I understood it, Apple told you the app was hanging and not displaying any relevant data, while here's you're mentioning a crash (which they would have told you about, and sent you the crash log). I fear there are other issues that this.

Comment: @jcaron : In log I found this `Terminating app due to uncaught exception`. I ask multiple times logs even if app is hanging, but apple never give them to me...

Comment: @satheesh : Honestly, just bcz of you I tried and found this issue... I believe all will face this issue if they upload the app with iOS 9.1

Answer (score 2):

Did you test using "Run" from Xcode, or using Test Flight? Test Flight gets you the app in the same environment as Apple gets it, while running directly from Xcode may yield different results (different push notification environment, possibly different compilation options...).

Also, do you have access to the logs of the server that the app queries? If so, have you checked them to see what happens when Apple try to use the app? Is the query correctly formed? Was there an error (status code different from 200, or in the error log)?

What kind of request does your app perform? Is it a regular http(s) request? Or are you using an unusual protocol which may be blocked somehow?

I suppose the server queried is fully reachable from the Internet (i.e. you did not put a server that is only accessible on your local network)?

You should add error handling in your code, to test the result of requests and display information about it, so that if there's an error when they test it, at least they can report what the error is.

Comment: I used diawi.com to check on iPhone by exporting  and its fine... the first screen I have is language screen where there is no connection with internet (no queries) but I have animation of images using `animationImages`

Comment: Have you checked that you don't make any assumptions about the environment (language, locale, time zone...)? Is your app universal or iPhone-only? Did you check on the iPhone 6 Plus (real or simulator)? If your app is universal, did you check on iPad (real or simulator)?

Comment: iPhone only... I checked on iPhone 4s, Iphone 5 & iPhone 6. I  don't have iPhone 6s  to test :( sadly..

Comment: Check iPad, a lot of times that is what Apple is testing on.  Even though it is an iPhone only App, it has to run on iPad in compatibility mode.

Comment: thanks for your concern. finally I managed to get the issue and I resolved it... Check my answer for the same...