# iOS Application hangs up when started from TestFlight or AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store, testflight, freeze

I have developed an iOS application, which has signup process. When started in debug the application is working as expected.

When the application is installed trough TestFlight or AppStore the following scenario occurs:

When starting from the application icon on the home screen everything works as expected.

When starting from TestFlight or AppStore via the "Open" button the application hangs after the signup process is successfully completed.

The application can be downloaded from the following URL: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/treffn-we-make-meeting-up-easy/id1137059844?ls=1&mt=8

The two outcomes can be observed if you reinstall the application. The application doesn't crash so I don't have any crash reports.

I'm looking for a way to simulate such launch in debug so I can trace what is happening or any ideas on what might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While asking some of friends around. I understood that the Launch Options are providing additional parameters when launching the application directly from the AppStore or trough TestFlight.

I have found a similar question, which helped me solve my issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34118249/1913174

When you are handling the launch options parameter you should always handle only the cases, which matter to you. In all other cases you should allow your application to behave as started from the icon. In my case I'm handling start from push notification and start from Quick Action. I was storing the launch options each time the application was not started from a Quick Action, which lead to the point when I was trying to handle Push Notification data, which didn't existed.